# Autostart not working for video html

Tags: html, tags, embed

I am using  tag to display my video on the page. When the page is loaded, the video gets started automatically.

To prevent this , I use autostart="false". But no Luck.

My code :

```
<embed style="max-width:180px; max-height:135px;" src="url" autostart="false" loop="true">
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

If it is an strictly an embed, usually you just have to put autostart="false" within the embed tag.

**EXAMPLE**:

```
<embed autostart="false">
```

If it is an object (which is recommended), you will want to use a param.

**EXAMPLE**:

```
<object width="160" height="144">
<param name="autoplay" value="false">

<embed src="sample.mov" width="160" height="144" autoplay="false" controller="false"
</embed>
```

Comment: I want to use embed only. Any fixes?

Comment: Actually, as i suggested in my answer, the recommended solution will be to use the second option only. But if you want to use embed only, the first solution shall work. Sometimes, Firefox has problem detecting autostart = "false". You might be facing issue due to it. So, i recommend you to use second option. Do upvote and accept my answer if it helps :)